# created_atのタイムゾーンとフォーマットを変換する

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, erb

例えば下記のようにerb上に書くとGMTで表示されるかと思いますが、コレを2015年3月4日10:30みたいなフォーマットにしたい場合はどうすればいいでしょうか
`<%= comment.created_at %>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strftime`を使うと、毎回書式文字列を指定しなければなりません。
なので、書式文字列は`ja.yml`に書いて、`I18n.l`メソッド（Viewの中では`l`だけで呼び出せる）を使うのがベターだと思います。

```
# config/locales/ja.yml
ja:
  time:
    formats:
      default: ! '%Y/%m/%d'
      long: ! '%Y年%m月%d日(%a) %H時%M分%S秒 %z'
      short: ! '%Y年%m月%d日 %H:%M'
```

```
# view
<%= l comment.created_at, format: :short %>
```

```
# config/application.rb
config.time_zone = 'Tokyo'
config.i18n.default_locale = :ja
```

このあたりの仕組みを詳しく知りたい場合はRailsガイドを読んでみてください。

http://railsguides.jp/i18n.html

Answer (score 1):

`strftime`を利用します。

```
<%= comment.created_at.strftime('%Y年%m月%d日 %H:%M') %>
```

Comment: `strftime` だけだとタイムゾーンが GMT/UTC のままでは？